# bytearray(byte object) cant append timestamp

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, struct, byte

I am trying to add a timestamp to the beginning of a byte object that has hex values, however I am having some issues.

My byte obejct (data) that i want to append a timestamp to index 0 , looks as such :

```
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00`\xc2\xf5(\x00\x00\x00\x00x\x00\x00\x00!\xa1\x07\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00x\x00\x00\x00\xf5\x00\x00\x00}\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x98\xe0\x0e\x00 \xa1\x07\x00\xac\r\x00\x00P\xc3\x00\x00o\x12\x83\x00"\x00\x00\x00P\xc3\x00\x00)\\\x8f\x02\xac\x00\x00\x00\xe4\x14\x1d-B\xcff-\x8f\xc2\xf5(\xebQP\xc3(\\\xccLx\x00\x86qd\x00L\x1d}\x00\xf5\x00L\x1d\xb5\x012\x00\x10\'\xcc\x0c\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00l\xe7\xfb)\x00\x00\x00\x00`\xc2\xf5(\xd0\x07\xd0\x07\xfa\x00\xfa\x00\xd0\x07\xd0\x07\x01\x00\x01\x00\xc4\t\xc4\t\xc7\x01\x00\x00\xd0\x07\xee\x02\x8f\xc2\xf5(+\xf6\x97)\xc4\tzT\x05\x02\xb8\x0b\x00\x00\x05\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x08<\x0f2\x00\n\x01K\x00\x00\x00\xc4\t\x00\x04\x07@\x01\x00\x00\x00'
```

I have tried to insert a timestamp this way :

```
import struct, time 
import numpy as np
g = bytearray(data)
time_ = struct.pack("I",int(time.time()))
g.append(int(time_))
```

My error is the following:

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'\x11\xb2\x90X'

How may I go about this?

Comment: You're converting the number to bytes already, so there's no need to try to convert it back to a number, but you should clarify where exactly you're trying to put the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [878]: g=bytearray([])
In [879]: import struct, time
In [880]: time_ = struct.pack("I",int(time.time()))
In [881]: time_
Out[881]: b'U\xc5\x90X'
```

The error is produced by trying to interpret `time_` as an integer:

```
In [886]: int(time_)
...
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'U\xc5\x90X'
```

But appending `time_` also does not work, because it has multiple bytes:

```
In [882]: g.append(time_)
...
TypeError: an integer is required
In [883]: g.append?
Signature: g.append(item, /)
Docstring:
Append a single item to the end of the bytearray.
```

But extend does work:

```
In [884]: g.extend(time_)
In [885]: g
Out[885]: bytearray(b'U\xc5\x90X')
```

`int(time)` is an integer, which occupies 4 bytes:

```
In [887]: int(time.time())
Out[887]: 1485882974
In [888]: len(time_)
Out[888]: 4
```